# How can one drag an ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I've spent some time researching this and still haven't found a great answer.

What I would like is to drag an ImageView around the screen. Not a drag and drop, but just an actual drag.

This tutorial has been helpful:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-gesture--mobile-2239

It works perfect, but it's designed to drag a bitmap, not an ImageView. I've tried replacing the Bitmap with an ImageView, but I'm not sure how the Canvas and ImageView interact in the onDraw method. I've tried imageView.draw(canvas); and that doesn't seem to work - the ImageView doesn't show up at all.

Bitmaps are not idea, because you can't add borders to them like you can with an ImageView.

I'd also like to be able to fling the ImageView off the screen.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not that complected. You just have you use a listener on the ImageView. It can be 'ondraglistener' or 'ontouchlistener'.

Answer (score 1):

You can create RelativeLayout that match all your screen. In the layout create ImageView.

Set `OnTouchListener` listener to your relative layout to handle your finger coordinate.

After that you can write something like this :

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            move(event);
        }
    }


    public void move(MotionEvent event)
    {
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mImageView.getLayoutParams();
         layoutParams.topMargin = event.getY();
         layoutParams.leftMargin = event.getX();
         mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

Like using method `move(MotionEvent event)` you can drag your imageView where you want.

I hope this help you!

Comment: That's great! How would I go about implementing a fling?

Comment: For some reason when I do this approach, if you hold down on the imageview, 2 images show up and flicker. Not ideal.

Comment: i don't know what is your real code and in this situation cannot answer. But i think in `onTouch` you receive very often new coordinate. You can try to filter received coordinate as check how long you move finger and if is more 5 or 10 px then move your imageView